# How to make a negative look ahead optional

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want a regular expression that allows:

- a string of one or more word characters
- ...that ends with an optional equal symbol, provided that the equal sign itself is followed by a non-word character (like a quote)

Passing (good):

```
dHlwZT1jJmFjY291bnQ9MSZjYW1wYWlnbj0xJnByb3NwZWN0PTEmd29ya2Zsb3c9MSZ0ZdddbGF0ZT0xJnVybD1odHRwFadsjasdJGJTJGcGluZ29tZXRlci5jb20=

dHlwZT1jJmFjY291bnQ9MSZjYW1wYWlnbj0xJnByb3NwZWN0PTEmd29ya2Zsb3c9MSZ0ZW1wbGF0ZT0xJnVASdfjhksdwJTNBJTJGJTJGcGluZ29tZXRlci5jb20="
```

**Not passing (bad) - the `=` at the end should be optional:**

```
dHlwZT11JmFjY291bnQ9asdfasdfjnYW1wYWlnG0xJnByb3NwZWN0PTEmd29ya2Zsb3c9MSZ0ZW1wbGF0ZT0x
```

Not passing (good):

```
dHlw=ZT1jJmFjY291bnQ9MSZjYW1wYWlnbj0xJnByb3NwZWN0PTEmd29ya2Zsb3c9MSZ0ZW1wbGF0ZT0=xJnVybD1asdfasdfsadfwJTNBJTJGJTJGcGluZ29tZXRlci5jb20=3D
```

Here is what I have so far:

Regex:

`([\w]+)=(?!\w)`

Demo:

http://rubular.com/r/JgPKSaJIri

Comment: your first "Passing" sample ends with an equal sign that isn't followed by anything. That's not what your description asks for. Which is correct?

Comment: @Amit that is acceptable. so, `...ABC=` or `...ABC="` should be valid but `...A=BC` should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
([\w]+)=?(?=\W$)
```

**Changes made**

- We can use a positive lookahead for anything other than `\w` ( which is `\W` )
- Add `$` to anchor the regex at the end of the string.

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/aKdyxLPB7I)

Comment: Thanks! So close - I just want to include the equal sign in the match result if it's valid.

Comment: @okoboko Sorry for that, just move the `=` to outside, that will capture `=` as well. Corrected in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
^\w+=?\b\W*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to validate base64 input, then the specification in the question is underspecified and disallow valid base64 inputs which contain `+` or `/` (or other character, [depending on the context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)).

You might want to use [`strict_decode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_decode64) or [`urlsafe_decode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_decode64) to try decode the string and catch the exception when the string is incorrectly specified (which one to use exactly depends on your use case). Both functions don't like line separator, so you need to strip them from the encoded string before decoding.